# Problem Updating Values from MultiIndex Dataframe after using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem updating some values in a MultiIndex Dataframe. I have a Dataframe with multiple data types (bool, int, float)

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['idx1'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df['idx2'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df['abool'] = True
df['a'] = np.arange(5, dtype='int64')
df['b'] = np.arange(5, dtype='float64')
df['c'] = np.arange(5, dtype='int64')
df = df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'])

df
```

The result is

```
           abool  a    b  c
idx1 idx2                  
0    0      True  0  0.0  0
1    1      True  1  1.0  1
2    2      True  2  2.0  2
3    3      True  3  3.0  3
4    4      True  4  4.0  4
```

If I change some values, the interpreter do the changes

```
idx = [(1,1),(3,3)]
df.loc[idx, 'c'] = 0
df.loc[idx, 'c']
```

```
idx1  idx2
1     1       0
3     3       0
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

But when I call a loc function

```
df.loc[idx, ['a', 'b']]
```

```
           a    b
idx1 idx2        
1    1     1  1.0
3    3     3  3.0
```

Now, I try to modify the values of the column C again and the changes can't be applied.

```
df.loc[idx, 'c'] = 15
df.loc[idx, 'c']
```

```
idx1  idx2
1     1       0
3     3       0
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

I can still make changes to other columns, but I can't modify the values in column C that I want. Also, if I put the column C into a list (and return a DataFrame), I can see the changes, but if I call the column C as series, I can't still view the changes.

```
df.loc[idx, ['c']]
```

```
            c
idx1 idx2    
1    1     15
3    3     15
```

I can't understand why this happens. I will appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Recently I ran this script on pandas 1.3.5 and the behavior is as expected. Since pandas 1.4.0 I get the problem.

Comment: I see these functions are not the same but both should display the same value (the first as DataFrame and the second as Series) and it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

You're not crazy, this is definitely a bug, I do not know if it is known.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['idx1'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df['idx2'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df['abool'] = True
df['a'] = np.arange(5, dtype='int64')
df['b'] = np.arange(5, dtype='float64')
df['c'] = np.arange(5, dtype='int64')
df['c'] = np.arange(5)
df = df.set_index(['idx1','idx2'])

idx = [(1,1),(3,3)]
df.loc[idx, 'c'] = 0
df.loc[idx, 'c']
df.loc[idx, ['a', 'b']] # <-- This line screws everything up, and idk why...
df.loc[idx, 'c'] = 15
df.loc[idx, 'c']
```

Output with that line:

```
idx1  idx2
1     1       0
3     3       0
Name: c, dtype: int64

           a    b
idx1 idx2
1    1     1  1.0
3    3     3  3.0

idx1  idx2
1     1       0
3     3       0
Name: c, dtype: int64
--------------------------
>>> df['c']
idx1  idx2
0     0       0
1     1       0
2     2       2
3     3       0
4     4       4
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>> df[['c']]
            c
idx1 idx2
0    0      0
1    1     15
2    2      2
3    3     15
4    4      4
```

Output without that line:

```
idx1  idx2
1     1       0
3     3       0
Name: c, dtype: int64

           a    b
idx1 idx2
1    1     1  1.0
3    3     3  3.0

idx1  idx2
1     1       15
3     3       15
Name: c, dtype: int64
--------------------------
>>> df['c']
idx1  idx2
0     0        0
1     1       15
2     2        2
3     3       15
4     4        4
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>> df[['c']]
            c
idx1 idx2
0    0      0
1    1     15
2    2      2
3    3     15
4    4      4
```

[image: 1.4.3]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't duplicate the problem:

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer with the same script as pictured here. Mine's `1.4.3`, and they're showing as `int64` instead of `int32`. Odd

Comment: @BeRT2me Wow!  This is really strange.  Maybe numpy version issue.

Comment: Possibly, for testing I set up a new environment, just installing python3.10 and pandas (plus the auto-install of dependencies) and had this issue. I can replicate the issue by replacing the `np.arange` with `[0,1,2,3,4]` and `[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]` respectively.

Comment: It's actually because column c is defined as int32 on line 13 of your script. Also, I tried removing line 13 and changing the dtype on line 12 to int32 and got the same results as you, but setting the dtype to int64 I get the problem again. It's strange. I run the script with pandas 1.4.2 and numpy 1.23.1

Comment: I set mine up just like Scott's with the same line 13 and reproduced the error. @BryanBizarro

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it on the `main` branch of `pandas`, so it's probably already known and fixed, just waiting for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the DataFrame as per the documentation. I think the problem is in the `MultIndex`. There is a method in pandas to enter it. `pd.MultiIndex.` See how it turned out.

```
tuples = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

values = {'abool': True, 
        'a': np.arange(5, dtype='int64'), 
        'b': np.arange(5, dtype='float64'),
        'c': np.arange(5, dtype='int64')}

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index)
df
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html